# Proper wiring of ceiling fan with a remote and one wall switch

Tags: ceiling-fan

Wiring from the Ceiling:
Black
Red
White
Copper ground

Wiring from Remote:
Input side: black and white wires
Output side: white, black, blue, and green (ground)

Wiring from Fan motor:
black, white, blue, green (ground)

The fan is turned on from a single wall switch.  I want to power the fan from the wall switch and then use the remote to change fan speed and the light.

How do I wire this combination?
Thanks!

Comment: This is a common question here. Use the search feature to find duplicates

Comment: You may notice almost every room has a light switch in an obvious location.  Building codes require at least one switch exist and *turn on a light*.  You can't have *all the lights* on unusual methods. When this switch no longer operates a light, will you still comply with building codes?